# ¿Cómo graficar valores mayores a 0 en un plot?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

Hola que tal? Tengo un programa para poder graficar los datos de un archivo .txt, el cual es el siguiente:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib
import pandas as pd 


fig_size = [20, 18]
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = fig_size

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

data = pd.read_csv('MINIMOS.txt',header = 1, delim_whitespace = True)

x = data.iloc[:,0]

y = data.iloc[:,1]

ax.plot(x, y, '-o',color ='red',  linewidth=2)

plt.xticks(range(0, 200, 18))

plt.yticks(range(0, 20, 3))

ax.grid()

plt.show()
```

Por ejemplo si tengo el siguiente Dataframe:

```
Hora Ampiltud
1.45   20.5
2.30   0.00
3.45   21.8
4.50   0.00
```

Deseo graficar los valores mayores a 0 en un plot, sin eliminar filas por que necesito usar esos valores.

¿Alguna ayuda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no quieres graficar los puntos en los que la amplitud es mayor que 0, basta con eliminar esas filas del DataFrama. Tienes varias posibilidades, por ejemplo:

- Crear un nuevo DataFrame usando un filtro boleno:

  ```
  plot_data = data[data["Amplitud"] > 0]
  ```

  esto deja intacto el `DataFrame` original `data` por si necesitas los datos con posterioridad.
- Si quisieras eliminar las filas del DataFrame in-place:

  ```
  data.drop(data.index[data['Amplitud'] <= 0], inplace=True)
  ```

El ejemplo reproducible completo:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib
import pandas as pd 
import io



csv = io.StringIO("""\
Hora   Amplitud
1.45   20.5
2.30   0.00
3.45   21.8
4.50   0.00
""")

fig_size = [20, 18]
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = fig_size

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

data = pd.read_csv(csv, header=0, delim_whitespace=True)
plot_data = data[data["Amplitud"] > 0]
x = plot_data.iloc[:,0]
y = plot_data.iloc[:,1]

ax.plot(x, y, '-o',color='red',  linewidth=2)
plt.xticks(range(0, 200, 18))
plt.yticks(range(0, 20, 3))
ax.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: hola, ¿como he puesto en la pregunta como puedo graficar solamente los datos mayores a cero?.

Comment: Hola Rocker, simplemente cambia el filtro de `data = data[data["Amplitud"] != 0]` a `data = data[data["Amplitud"]  > 0]`. He editado la respuesta.